# Extrair numeros de uma lista usando Regex

Tags: python, regex

Tenho a seguinte lista

```
<type 'list'>: [u'1',u'2'',u'3',u'4',u'7']
```

O resultado que espero é:

```
1 2 3 4 7
```

Tentei usar o `re.findall(r'\d+', variavel)`

Mas ele não funciona, note que também preciso

Comment: Voce parece estar confundindo alguns conceitos básicos - 
Em Python, uma ista é uma sequência de objetos arbitrários. Regexps funcionam para strings, e acham apdrões dentro do texto - Uma string é bem diferente de um objeto em Python - a maior parte dos objetos tem uma representação em texto - mas essa visão não reflete o seu conteúdo.  Ademais, o próprio `re.findall`  retrona uma lista.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso com o [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#map):

```
lista = [u'1', u'2', u'3', u'4', u'7']

outraLista = list(map(int, lista))
print (outraLista) # [1, 2, 3, 4, 7]
```

Ou usar [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) para retornar um objeto inteiro:

```
lista = [u'1', u'2', u'3', u'4', u'7']

outraLista = [int(item) for item in lista if item.isdigit()]
print (outraLista) # [1, 2, 3, 4, 7]
```

Se quiser continuar a usar [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall), passe a lista como uma *string* com [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str):

```
import re

lista = [u'1', u'2', u'3', u'4', u'7']

outraLista = re.findall('\d+', str(lista))

for item in outraLista:
    print (item)
```

Answer (score 1):

Para listas dessa maneira você pode fazer assim:

```
lista = [u'1', u'2', u'5', u'3', u'9', u'1']
result = [x for x in lista if re.match(r"\d+", x) ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Você não precisa usar expressões regulares para isso, só se o que você procura estivesse em uma grande string , ai a regex buscaria um padrão e retornaria os que casariam com ele..

Mas se você já tem uma lista qualquer e quer extrair somente os números basta usar uma função que verifique cada elemento da lista verificando se ele é digito ou não.

Filter: Executa uma função sobre cada elemento da lista, e filta somente os que retornam verdadeiro.

```
>>> lista_qualquer = [u'1',u'2',u'3',u'4',u'7','teste','casa']
>>> e_um_numero = lambda numero : numero:isdigit()
>>> numeros = filter(e_um_numero,lista_qualquer)
```

E para converter cada elemento da lista somente com números para inteiros basta usar o `map` que executa uma função sobre cada elemento da lista.

```
>>> numeros = map(int,numeros)
[1,2,3,4,7]
```